# Rails se desinstala solo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Estoy tratando de aprender `Ruby on Rails` y me ha costado bastante empezar por temas de configuración. Ayer estaba siguiendo un tutorial, así que instalé Ruby y después rails con `gem install rails`, y todo funcionaba bien. Pero hoy al querer seguir e iniciar mi servidor salio un error. Al final tuve que volver a instalar Rails. Pero sigo sin poder iniciar el servidor y me sale este error:

> 'Could not find proper version of railties (4.0.0) in any of the
>   sources Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.'

Alguien me puede decir ¿Qué pasó? quizás lo instalé mal la primera vez. ¿Cómo soluciono este error que tengo ahora?

Gracias.

Comment: Buenas, ¿podrías decir como has instalado Ruby (mediante los paquetes del sistema, RVM, rbenv, etc.), que versión de rails has instalado (`gem list rails`) y el contenido del `Gemfile`? Saludos.

Comment: instalar rails 4.0.0.rc1.  Me di cuenta que el problema era solo dentro la carpeta de mi proyecto. ya que afuera de  mi proyecto hice rails -v y me entrego la version sin problemas, y adentro daba error

Answer (score 1):

Has intentado usar RVM como gestor de versiones de Ruby, posiblemente tu error o problema radique en que lo instalaste como gema del sistema lo cual no es recomendable ya que el sistema operativo genera algunos errores con las gemas y versiones de ruby, intenta instalando RVM primero y luego instalas las versiones de rails que necesites, RVM te permite tener multiples versiones de Ruby y conjuntos de gemas diferentes por proyecto, por eso su nombre Ruby Version Manager(RVM)

si usas linux o macOS instenta correr este comando:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

cuando te haya instalado eso intentas instalar una version de Ruby, puede ser la stable:

```
rvm install stable
```

y por ultimo instalas rails:

```
gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

saludos y espero te sirva de algo.

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje te dice que escribas en la linea de comandos:

```
bundle install
```

Quizás esto solucione tu situación.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que deberías especificar en que sistema operativo lo estas intentando, si es en linux http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-ubuntu.html
 y para windows http://railsinstaller.org/en, te recomiendo que uses linux.

Hay gems que no van bien o simplemente no funcionan en windows.

Espero te sirva, saludos

Comment: Omar, esto parece mas un comentario. Cuando tengas suficiente reputación podrás hacer comentarios. Esto no responde la pregunta que el OP plantea. Si pudieras [editar] tu respuesta para responder la pregunta sería bueno. Saludos!